# How to tackle sugar addiction

Tags: food, junkfood

My toddlers like to have ice-cream, candy, sweet, and high sugar cookies. I just worried it could lead to sugar addiction. What are persuasive techniques to reduce sugar intake?

Comment: They are toddlers.  Stop giving them sugar. You are the parent and make the decisions.

Comment: for toddlers this is easy, just don't have any sugar at home. and later, just educate them about how it sucks to have tooth decay, maybe with pictures from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tooth_decay

Comment: -Sarcasm- Feed then sugar until they're sick. /sarcam

Have you tried other sweet foods that don't have processed sugars? Fruits especially are a great source of non-processed sugar, and can help them to realize that there's other options for sweet foods. I'm personally particular to strawberries, but there's other fruits. What my mother did growing up was to try exotic fruits with me, and served as a fun bonding exercise with her.

Comment: @Anoplexian Processed sugars are bad primarily because they show up in things you wouldn’t expect to have them (read: things that aren’t particularly sweet), and show up in quantities larger than you might otherwise expect (read: more than you would usually find in nature). Gram for gram, there is little difference in the nutritional value of natural vs. processed sugars. As far as sugar is concerned, swapping processed sources for natural sources will only help if it causes you to *consume less sugar*. Which it may or may not. It also may or may not provide additional nutrients with the sugar

Comment: On which point, may I just offer a general warning that modern nutritional science is, unfortunately, a rather problematic field? Unfortunately, the overwhelming majority of nutritional studies are funded by various food producers, with clear conflicts of interest, and a great deal of nutritional information is peddled without *even* potentially-conflicted studies being performed. Already I see answers that include information I believe to be without scientific basis. I suggest that the expertise of this site is in *parenting*, so focus on answers suggesting parenting techniques, not diets.

Comment: Not a full answer, but a tip on how you can replace sweets: Sugar-free muffins and cookies are easy to make! Sugar free in this case means: you have bananas or dates as the sweetening factor. This way, they will get their MILD sweetness, but not the sugar-rush. Any fruit as a snack works well, too. You can turn pureed fruit into popsicles, too! This way, you can replace the "sugar" sugar with fruity varieties. Source: it's how I kicked my sugar-habit without missing much! You DO get something sweet... but not _a_ sweet :).

Comment: In addition to the above: still allow occasional sweets, but in small amounts. But hopefully, your kids will end up liking the home-made cookies (especially if they can participate in making them!) a lot more anyway!

Comment: If they ask you for ice cream and you say "no", that should be a pretty persuasive technique to reduce sugar intake for a toddler. Your fundamental question seems to be "How do I stop giving ice cream and cookies to my toddler?", and the answer is "Stop giving ice cream and cookies to your toddler."

Comment: @Layna That will cut out processed sugar, but calling those pastries sugar-free is a pretty large stretch if they contain banana.

Comment: @Patrick: I yield: added-sugar-free. Unless someone comes up with a better term.

Comment: @user26407 You're basically assuming that since your toddlers like to have something, they will get it.I assure you, it will become problematic if you keep this policy in place when they grow up.

Comment: The answers on that all look relevant here. I'll close as dupe, despite the age difference

Answer (score 43):

There is an old Indian story:

> A lady and her son went to a monk asking about her son's sugar problem.
>
> The monk said, "Come back here in 10 days."
>
> After 10 days she went back to the monk with her son.
>
> Now the monk says to her son, "Kid, do not eat sugar. It is not good for your health."
>
> Surprised, the mother asked, "Why did you not say it before?"
>
> The monk replied, "10 days ago, I was eating a lot of sugar."

First you must change you eating habits and soon you will find he will start copying you.

If you eat fruits and enjoy them, your son will believe they are delicious. Moreover, your son can learn that there are lot of delicious things that are actually healthy for your toddler.

Comment: Adding into this: If there are no candies and ice-cream at home, how can he eat them? Stop stocking sweet things, and add some some fruits to the fridge

Comment: My mum eats mushrooms, but I don't recall her ever eating sweets. As a kid I ate sweets and not mushrooms (still true if I'm honest). So I'm not convinced leading by example will help much here (though of course being hypocritical won't work at all).

Answer (score 27):

**Edit**: scientific content deleted as I am not able to find, in reasonable time, the exact references needed to support it.

It will, in all likelihood, be unrealistic to really keep your toddlers away from sweets completely. That said:

- Eat less sweets yourself. You do not need to make a science of this, and you certainly do not need to count anything. You know if it tastes sweet. It is certainly possible to live completely normal without ever having any predominantly sweet taste in your mouth.
- Do not have cookies, sweets, ice cream etc. in the house. No joke - don't underestimate how easy it is to say "There are no more cookies" instead of saying "No, you already had 3 cookies, you can't have any more". If they throw a tantrum, you can tell them "ok, fetch yourself some from the kitchen" and wait until they themselves *see* that there are none. If you want to eat something sweet, buy it, eat it, and be done with it.
- Remove habitual eating. Avoid making it a habit to always pick up an ice cream when going to the kindergarten. Avoid *always* buying a little sweety at the store. Avoid *always* buying a chocolate bar after going swimming. And so on.
- Never give *any* food as reward or compensation.
- Check your favourite drinks. They usually have around 10g of sugar per 100ml and can increase to *much* more for certain beverages. That's 100g per liter. Do an experiment: weigh off 100g of sugar and put it into a 1L bottle. Afterwards, never buy those again, ever.
- Return to 3 larger (or 5 smaller or whatever fits in your schedule) fixed meals per day. Avoid having food with you when going out for short periods (to the playground etc.), so they get used to short periods with no food at all. If you want to have some "emergency" food with you (in case you miss a train or something), pick non-sweet ones: carrots, not-too-sweet fruits, sausages, cheese... . Obviously, if you spend a day in the woods, then you need to take food; make it primarily non-sweet.

Best of luck!

Comment: "drinks" are the worst. "fruit" drinks pack almost half as a sugar, a small pack for one person has around 800 calories, the 1L ones 5000

Comment: To be fair to the reader who does look at the material before the edit, no amount of time would suffice to find sources to your scientific claims, because there is no supporting evidence for them in the medical literature.

Comment: @anongoodnurse isn't the study mentioned here source enough?  http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-2039315/Sweet-cravings-triggered-falls-blood-sugar.html  The original seems to be https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4076145/  Also see http://medicine.yale.edu/lab/lombroso/research/article.aspx?id=1078, it may not be exactly as AnoE described but it's close.

Comment: @JimW - The first does not support the OP's claims. It does discuss the difference between glucose and fructose in the effect on **satiety hormones** (emphasis mine). It is known that *glucose* levels has an effect on the hypothalamus. This is quite different from the OP's deductions. Hunger and satiety are complicated physiological mechanisms, still not fully understood (new hormones are discovered every few months, it seems), and far, far more complex than presented here previously.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: Although I agree with your general statement, your calories are way off. A whole kg of pure sugar has 4000 kcal, 1L of Coca Cola has 380 kcal, 1L of (german) "fruit" drink has 420 kcal.

Comment: Thanks, I double checked and it is the same here...I could swear there was a specific brand where a small pack had too much kcal, but my memory can be betraying me.

Comment: I assume they don't give it to toddlers, but how about 4000kcal per "serving": http://www.livestrong.com/article/438117-weight-gainer-shakes-with-about-4-000-calories/ . :-) @RuiFRibeiro

Answer (score 3):

Try starting with smaller dishes, smaller portions, less often. Precede it with a physical activity like a walk or swim. Follow with a set ritual like tooth brushing an hour after sugary meals. (thanks Tony for that info!). Rishi is also correct. It starts with your example.  There are plenty of things (like alcohol or driving) that children are not allowed to do in spite of what their parent's can do, but good eating habits and exercise are best learned young. Teach moderation. Holidays and birthdays/parties are a fine time to go a little over the top.

Fruits are also filled with sugar. I would follow the guidelines of no more than 17 grams/170 calories per day. [LINK](http://www.livestrong.com/article/479749-how-much-sugar-should-a-toddler-eat-per-day/) The quote below is within the side articles but I could not directly link to it.

> According to the American Heart Association, toddlers should consume
>   only 17 g of sugar per day. If a toddler consumes between 1,200 and
>   1,400 calories, this means that between 7 and 8 percent of her total
>   calories should be from sugar. This equals out to about 170 calories
>   from sugar per day.Jun 17, 2015   **ON EDIT** Theses numbers are incorrect. I have done further research and it looks like now the AHA recommends no more that 100 calories from sugar for ages 2-6.**

I do warn that if you are very rigid about anything, children will often rebel later. I have vegan friends who were very rigid and to their shock and dismay, both their kids eat meat away from home.

Comment: 17 grams of sugar and 170 calories from sugar are two totally different amounts.

Comment: "Follow with a set ritual like tooth brushing." This is the opposite of what dentists recommend. You need to leave time after eating sugary foods before brushing your teeth: "Eating and drinking foods containing sugar and acids naturally weakens the enamel on your teeth. Brushing straight afterwards can cause tiny particles of enamel to be brushed away. It is best not to brush your teeth until at least one hour after eating." [source](https://www.dentalhealth.org/tell-me-about/topic/sundry/diet#faq_778)

Comment: @Tony  Thanks, I did not know that. I've done that all my life, on the advice of my dentist -- eons ago, though.

Comment: @UmbertoP. I did not do the math, the AHA* did, I did wonder, but I don't have the math. *That's a c&p.

Comment: There are [4 calories in a gram of sugar](http://www.heart.org/HEARTORG/HealthyLiving/HealthyEating/Nutrition/Sugar-101_UCM_306024_Article.jsp#.WLY29BDas0o) (AHA).

Comment: Thanks @anongoodnurse  further proof that you can't even trust the AHA website. I should have gone to another source when I was suspicious.

Comment: @WillowRex - I think it was just sloppy wording on the first site. I don't think you did anything wrong; it's hard to go wrong when you use good links, but it still happens sometimes because of context. :) I wouldn't have brought it up except for the challenge you received. Also, while I'm at it, the recommendation not to brush after acids (orange juice, soda, etc.) is relatively new. Never heard it said of sugar.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I need to be more careful. I am not able to access my pc, so links can be a problem.  I trusted even when I was suspicious. I am a bit bored so I am using my tab for entertainment until I can be home. It is a poor substitute.  Boredom is not a good reason for  inaccuracy.

Answer (score -1):

We all have "sugar addiction" ... craving something sweet is a pretty natural thing. The problem starts when too much refined sugar causes insulin/glucose peaks, and eventually child onset diabetes in young kids.

Sugar is a hell of a drug and weaning kids off sweets is pretty difficult at first, as they will be cranky and beg and act up to get sweets as a reward for good behavior. Never give them sweets for good behavior.

I find that well portioned freeze-dried fruits/berries are a really good way to to control sugar cravings and replace cookies, ice cream and other high-glucose snacks. Especially dried cranberries with (no sugar added) are pretty good, as well as dried pineapple, peaches, bananas.

Basically, find foods that are low on the [glycemic index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycemic_index) and avoid those artificial "fruit juices" targeted to kids that are mostly colored-sugar-water.